# Event Timeout At Kaa-Client

Tags: kaa

How long does kaa-client stores the event on the device that it has to send to the other clients, in case it is not able to successfully deliver in several attempts during the kaa-node server outage.

Is there a way I can set timeout in kaa-client untill it has to retry to send event on failure attempts?

Thanks
-Rizwan

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of the Kaa SDK on the Kaa client side in case of Operations server outage or inability to communicate depends on the failover model used on the client side. The default failover mechanism depends on the Kaa SDK type and platform.

See [Kaa Documentation](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/) for more information.